# CSS sprite - Image not displaying

Tags: html, css

I'm just trying to learn how to use sprites. 
I had the following code:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>
</div>
```

with the following css:

```
.jumbotron {
  background: url("../img/lsm1280.jpg");
  padding: 1em;
  height: 12.5em;
  width: 42em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

I'm trying to use css sprites.
So I've generated a png file using:  http://spritegen.website-performance.org/

And I've changed my css code to look like this:

```
.jumbotron {
  background: url("../img/csg-5267d2af270ac.png") no-repeat top left;
  padding: 1em;

  height: 12.5em;
  width: 42em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

And I'm trying to change the HTML code like so:

```
       <head> .... stuff
       <style>
          .sprite-lsm1280{ background-position: -7036px -1625px; width: 780px; height: 248px; } "
       </style>
      </head>
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <img class="sprite-lsm1280"/>
          </div>
```

I've been reviewing the comments in the following post: 
[Can't get CSS Sprite to work..what am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401602/cant-get-css-sprite-to-work-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

I'm going through each answer to see what I'm doing wrong..  but haven't found it yet. 
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

I've been playing around with the developer tools in my browser, and now I see that an image is being loaded, but it's the wrong one!
I've been changing the size of the container's height / width property and that's how I've determined that the image is loading... but just not the right one.

When I used the online tool to generate the css sprite, it created a bunch of classes for me, including the one below:

```
  .sprite-lsm1280{ background-position: -7036px -1625px; width: 780px; height: 248px; }
```

That's the css I've been trying to use on the image tag.  But it seems like the background position is incorrect...
I'm not sure how to fix this / test to prove that that's the case... 
Thanks.

Comment: what, exactly, is the issue?

Comment: @jbenjohnson I think he can't get css sprites to work.

Comment: Try first to remote background-repeat just in case the position is wrong. It might give you a hint about the image itself loading correctly.

Comment: adrenalin, i tried that ... still doesn't work.  Based on the answers found in the other post, I've made sure I have height, width sepcified.. and I've tried removing the repeat top left setting.

Comment: Please see my "EDIT 1" for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your edit one you are making a mistake.

Don't aplly the class `.sprite-lsm1280` to the img . Apply this next to the class of your div it must be like this

```
<div class="jumbotron sprite-lsm1280">

</div>
```

Because the class `.sprite-lsm1280` is moving your background to an specific position.